# R: automatically copy large amounts of data

Tags: r, reshape

I'm new in R, I have some data like this:

```
Yes No age    color  place
12  5  12-18  red    right
2   33 19-30  yellow left
...
```

I need to create new database,

```
answer   age    color  place
Yes      12-18  red    right 
Yes      12-18  red    right
...                          (12 times)

No       12-18  red    right
No       12-18  red    right
...                          (5 times)
```

How could I do?

Comment: @RichardErickson, how is that a possible duplicate? The linked question is about taking an `ftable` object and converting it to a `data.frame`. It has nothing to do with expanding the values out. Each part of the solution might be a duplicate, but I don't recall this particular combination as a question.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, You're correct. I'm sorry for messing up the flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a combination of `expandRows` from my "splitstackshape" package and `melt` from "reshape2".

Assuming your data are called "mydf", try:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(reshape2)
dfLong <- expandRows(
  melt(mydf, measure.vars = c("Yes", "No"), 
       variable.name = "answer"), "value")
```

Here are the first 20 rows:

```
head(dfLong, 20)
#        age  color place answer
# 1    12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.1  12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.2  12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.3  12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.4  12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.5  12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.6  12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.7  12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.8  12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.9  12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.10 12-18    red right    Yes
# 1.11 12-18    red right    Yes
# 2    19-30 yellow  left    Yes
# 2.1  19-30 yellow  left    Yes
# 3    12-18    red right     No
# 3.1  12-18    red right     No
# 3.2  12-18    red right     No
# 3.3  12-18    red right     No
# 3.4  12-18    red right     No
# 4    19-30 yellow  left     No

## Confirm that there are the correct number of combinations
table(dfLong$age, dfLong$answer)
#        
#         Yes No
#   12-18  12  5
#   19-30   2 33
```

The order is a little bit different from what you've posted--doing all "Yes" answers first and then the "No" answers instead of alternating between them.

Comment: Or with `gather()` from `tidyr`: `expandRows(tidyr::gather(df, answer, value, -age, -color, -place), "value")`

Comment: THX.
If I want to set the new database output as .csv, how should i do?

Comment: @JefferyChen: Take a look at `?write.table()`

Comment: @JefferyChen, no problem. If this answered your question, do consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow check-mark to the left of the answer area.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré, isn't `tidyr::gather` essentially `reshape2::melt`? See `tidyr:::gather_.data.frame`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yes, pretty similar but as mentionned in http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/: "*just as reshape2 did less than reshape, tidyr does less than reshape2. It’s designed specifically for tidying data, not general reshaping. In particular, existing methods only work for data frames, and tidyr never aggregates. This makes each function in tidyr simpler: each function does one thing well.*"